# Deleting minimum node from BST results in segmentation fault C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I am trying to delete the minimum node from a BST. But I get a seg fault.

To my understanding, minimum node will have no children, hence deleting it would not result in desserted leftover subtree. I am unsure on how to remove a node from a BST, I saw some solution that uses free() instead of delete. Where did I go wrong?

Source code for testing:
https://onlinegdb.com/kiOZQee3w

1. Codes are in bst.hpp
2. Constructor starts at line 23
3. insert function
   starts at line 96
4. delete_min function starts at line 142
5. min
   function starts at line 180 to 203

***Added some code in editing

```
void delete_min()
{
    Node* min_node = min();
    Node* min_parent = min_node->parent; //Added this
    
    if(!root)
    {
        return;
    }

    // If min is root (Added this)
    if(!root->left)
    {
        auto tmp = root;
        root = root->right;
        delete tmp;
        return;
    }

    min_parent->left = min_node->right; //Added this
    delete min_node;
    --size;    
}

Node* min()
{
    if(root == nullptr)
    {
        return root;
    }
    else
    {
        return min(root);
    }
}

Node* min(Node* node)
{
    while(node->left != nullptr)
    {
        node = node->left;
    } 
    return node;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] show a [mcve] (including `main`, the code that creates the BST, all necessary declarations, the `#include`s and a simple example of input that triggers the problem. IOW something that can be copy/pasted and compiled.

Comment: The minimum node won't have a *left* child – *right* child still might be, consider the most simple case of root being 1 and its right child being 2...

Comment: Have you made sure that all your nodes' child pointers are actually initialised to `nullptr` on constructing and reset back to on deleting an existing child? At least the latter is not done in the code you provided. Hint: You need the minimum's parent node for, too!

Comment: You're only destroying the node, you're not removing it from the tree. This leaves a dangling pointer in its parent. Use pen(cil) and paper and draw what needs to happen before you write the code.

Comment: Your edited code doesn't appear to be erroneous – most likely you already have an error on *building* the tree that is only revealed with delay on deletion. Have you correctly initialised the child pointers to `nullptr` on new nodes? You should provide a [mre]!

Comment: Working example on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/qf8eWKT3M) using your code from question unmodified...

Comment: Off-topic – about design: As you seem to use global variables you are able to maintain *exactly one single* BST. And if you need more than one??? Better is creating a separate class of which the root is a *private* root. `Node` as implementation detail should get nested class, its parent and child pointers again made private (your BST class then must be friend to be able to access the pointers). Private access to class members assures that no user can (legally) break your BST from outside...

Comment: @Aconcagua added the source code and listed the parts that is related to this problem. Tried to put the codes here but figured it would be slightly better to use online compiler as it looks quite complicated.

Comment: Code in question actually doesn't match the one in online GDB – where you introduced an additional error you didn't have before... Never mind, problem is now a double error, see my updated answer.

Comment: By the way: You should get used to debugging – you could inspect at runtime every step done by your implementation, you might have found the error on your own. General advice: If you do unit tests, then think well about which conditions to check. In your case, for instance, you might have wanted to add some checks if the tree structure is yet intact, including all children correctly pointing to their respective parent. That's a condition getting violated by your code.

Comment: By the way 2: You should get used to implement a constructors initialiser list (not to be confused with `std::initializer_list`), this avoids default initalisation + assignment in favour of direct initialisation by value; be aware that some member types (references, constant ones, non-default-constructable ones, ...) *only* can be initialised that way. In your case your constructor would have looked like: `Node(T k = T(), Node* input_node = nullptr) : key(k), parent(input_node) { }`. You don't need the default constructor anyway, so you rather might want to drop it, too...

Comment: (And if you indeed needed one a default value might *alternatively* have replaced it, too: `Node(T k = T(), Node* input_node = nullptr);`.)

Comment: Finally: As this is a template construction of `T` might be expensive in some cases; you might instead of accepting elements to insert by value accept them as const reference – at `insert` and at the node's constructor, that avoids two unnecessary copies. If you want to support move semantics, then add for each of both an overload accepting an rvalue reference, that can avoid copying internal data for many types (like e.g. `std::string`'s data) – don't forget moving(!):

Comment: `Node(T&& k, Node* input_node = nullptr) : key(std::move(k)), parent(input_node) { } void insert(T&& k) { /* ... */ new Node(std::move(k)); /* ... */ }`. You can avoid duplicate code by extracting the finding of the parent into its own function and call it from the two overloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At very first your assumption that the minimum node doesn't have children is wrong; it doesn't have a left child, but it *might* have a right child; consider the most simple case of the root node and one single child that's greater than:

```
  1
   \
    2
```

Then for removing a node you cannot just only delete it, but you need to adjust it's parent's left pointer, too – or the root pointer, if the root is the minimum node. You can simply set it to the minimum's right child (can either of another node or a null pointer).

*Update* according to the code code provided on online GDB (this version is not matching the version in the question!):

```
Node* min_node = min();
if(min_node->right != nullptr)
{
    min_node->parent->left = min_node->right;
}

delete min_node;
```

You need to update the parent's left child *unconditionally* – if there's no grandchild, you'll just copy the null pointer that way, which is fine, as there won't be a right child any more anyway (the only one gets deleted).

But *if* there's a grandchild you need to update its parent (which otherwise would remain pointing to the deleted node, thus get dangling!):

```
Node* min_node = min();
min_node->parent->left = min_node->right;
if(min_node->right)
{
    min_node->right->parent = min_node->parent;
}

delete min_node;
```

<s>For this, though, you need the parent node available, too, thus you need to adjust the lookup of the minimum appropriately *unless* your nodes contain a link to their respective parent, too. Assuming this not being the case then your iteration might look as follows:</s>

```
void deleteMin()
{
    // special handling: empty tree
    if(!root)
    {
        return;
    }

    // special handling: minimum is root
    if(!root->left)
    {
        auto tmp = root;
        root = root->right;
        delete tmp;
        return;
    }

    // now look for the minimum as you had already, but keep
    // track of the parent node as well!
    auto parent = root;
    child = root->left;
    while(child->left)
    {
        parent = child;
        child = child->left;
    }
    // OK, minimum found; essential step: adjust its parent!
    parent->left = child->right; // works for both a child available or not
    // now can safely delete:
    delete child;
}
```

Comment: Yes I have a parent link to node, I edited the code above. I understood what you explained but I am still getting the same error. The min() will return the minimum node, if the tree is empty, it will return null. My line of thought now is to create pointers tht points to min_node and min_node's parent. Then assign the min_parent's left to min_node's right child. Then we only delete min_node. However, theres seg fault here.

Comment: @hen Actually you wouldn't need the parent pointer – `minNode->parent->left = minNode->right` is just as fine as long as `minNode` is not the root – which you already checked anyway (I'd look up the minNode only afterwards, by the way). But that's not an issue. I don't see anything going wrong in your edited code any more – the problem likely is just a consequence of an error occurring earlier when building the tree – if you insert a new node – do you assure that the child pointers are correctly initialised to nullptr? Hint: At best do so in the constructor!